# Google maps api v3 show cards instead of infowindow on mobile devices

Tags: google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3

When opening maps.google.com on a desktop machine browser, clicking on a marker opens an infowindow.

When opening maps.google.com on a **MOBILE** device browser, clicking on a marker opens a **CARD** at the bottom.

I'm using google maps api v3. Adding an info-window is easy. How can I add a card? Is there a component for that?

Code for adding an infowindow:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.close();
        infoWindow.setContent('Some text');
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Does the code for adding a card looks like this maybe??

```
var card = new google.maps.Card();
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        card.close();
        card.setContent('Some text');
        card.open(map, marker);
});
```

Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: There is no Google Maps Card. This must me managed at your level. There are a number of ways to detect if the user is on a mobile device. Once you know that, you can adapt your code to display the information the way you like (in an infowindow or somewhere else). You can do anything you want in the marker click event listener.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that there is such a plugin ready-to-use. It would have saved me some css work...

Answer (score 0):

I was making something similar if anyone needs that in a future I will post my solution. Create same map using iframe with one pointer, there should be a card info by default on a left top. Copy html of a card info, then copy css used by that card, add that css as a library to your webpage, create a wrapper for a map div, after initializing map using google api, append wrapper using jquery with card info html (or do any other jquery functionality to place it on event etc..).

example here, u can find what u need using inspect element tool:
http://mttc.eu/content/contacts